# react-hook-form FormProvider not working when using it from internal component library

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, npm-package

I use react-hook-form FormProvider in my FormContext component, like this: (this component is in my component library)

```
const FormContext: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  children,
  ...options
}) => {
  const formMethods = useForm(options);

  return (
    <FormProvider {...formMethods}>
      {children}
    </FormProvider>
  );
};

export default FormContext;
```

This is my component: (in Content component I use useFormContext hook)

```
<FormContext>
   <Content />
</FormContext>
```

When I run my app I got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'reset' of '(0 ,
> react_hook_form__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useFormContext)(...)' as
> it is null.

package.json in my internal component library:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-hook-form": "6.9.6",
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react-hook-form": ">=7.0.0",
  }
}
```

Comment: Running into this issue on v7.22.5 that we just recently updated to. Wrapping a component from a custom in-house library in a <FormProvider>. The imported component from the library uses `useFormContext`, and it's returning null. This wasn't happening on v7.21.0. In the past this was usually because the react-hook-form versions in the custom library and the app didn't match, but I've made sure they match and it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just fixed this issue in my case. What I ended up doing was matching some of the package's `tsconfig.json` settings to the app's settings. Specifically, I changed the following to match between the two:

```
...
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
...
```

I haven't poked at this to see which specific value fixed things, but I have a feeling it might have been the "lib" values. Maybe this will help?

[Edit] Also worth noting that I reverted back to v7.21.0, but I'm not sure that was the issue. I'll update it to current shortly and see if it's still working. [Edit 2] Looks like it's still working with v7.22.5.

---

**8/30/2022 UPDATE:** we are currently using **react-hook-form 7.34.2**. We also switched to using Parcel to build the package in the `prepack` script (which automatically runs before the `publish` script command). Parcel seems to work better than `tsc`.

We also set the `peerDependencies` to the exact version being used, and make sure the project(s) using the package has the same version of react-hook-form installed. If the versions differ, there's a good change it'll break, based on our experience.

Here is our current full `tsconfig.json` file, if it helps:

```
{
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "outDir": "dist",

    "noEmit": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. My library still does not work. I am using reac-hook-form 7.34.2

Comment: @jordiburgos Not sure if it'll help your situation, but I updated my post with more current info. Ours is working fine.